# "The movie was <so bad that> <so that> <such that> I turned it off." ; "He sings <so badly that> <so that> no one likes it."

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I remove adjectives and adverbs between "so" and "that"?
To find it out, I came up with some sentences:

**(1)** *The movie was **so bad that** I turned it off*.
without "bad":
**(1a)** *The movie was **so that** I turned it off*. — Is (1a) correct?
**(1b)** *The movie was **such that** I turned it off*. — Is (1b) correct?

**(2)** *He sings **so badly that** no one likes it*.
without "badly":
**(2a)** *He sings **so that** no one likes it*. — Is (2a) correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go review the dictionary definitions of *so*, *such that*, and *so that*.

1a is not correct or natural.  In 1, **so** is part of "so bad" and functions as an adverb; without the adjective it is not grammatical or clear what you're trying to say, because there isn't anything for *so* to modify.

1b is grammatically correct but does not sound very fluent or natural.  ["such that" expresses purpose or result](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/such-that), like "The horrors and brutality occurring within a country are *such that* the rest of the world cannot morally stand by."  I guess you mean "the movie was the kind of movie that made me turn it off" but this does not sound like a natural phrasing.

In 2a, I think you are confused about the use of ["so that"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/so-that) - it is normally used to express purpose, like "They turned up the lights *so that* we could see better."   In your sentence, it sounds like he is intentionally singing badly to make people not like something.

Comment: "_I think you should go review the dictionary definitions of so, such that, and so that._" - The process was reverse: looking up "so", "such that" and "so that" in dictionaries caused me to ask the question.